# Grouping certain rows into one row in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is the query that got me this result.

```
 SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) total_customers
FROM customer c
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC

    country   total_customers

1   India       2
2   Portugal    2
3   Argentina   1
4   Australia   1
5   Austria     1
6   Belgium     1
7   Chile       1
```

How can I group all the 1's  into a category Others?

Desired output:
   country   customers

```
1   India       2
2   Portugal    2
3   Others      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` and `group by`, twice:

```
select (case when total_customers = 1 then 'Others' else country end) as country,
       sum(total_customers) as customers
from (select country,
             count(distinct customer_id) as total_customers
      from customer c
      group by country
     ) c
group by (case when total_customers = 1 then 'Others' else country end);
```

Comment: Can you tell me where can I use it in my code. It throws an error using this code above `no such column as customers`

Comment: @sai_636 . . . That's because it answered your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You need `case` with `group by` clause :

```
select (case when customers = 1 then 'Others' else country end) country,
       sum(customers) customers
from table t
group by (case when customers = 1 then 'Others' else country end);
```

**EDIT :** For instance the preceding query would be implemented with subquery.

But, for this you can do :

```
select (case when country in ('India','Portugal') then country else 'others' end) as country,
       count(distinct customer_id) as customers
from table t
group by (case when country in ('India','Portugal') then country else 'others' end)
```

Comment: I have more values in country other than India, portugal. I included only those two for demo in the question? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your query in another query to aggregate again. `GROUP BY` a `CASE`, that returns the country or `'Other'` based on the count. The `ORDER BY` gets a little tricky as you'd have to reuse the aforementioned case in it, to sort `Others` after all other countries. First check if the `CASE` returns `'Others'`, then returns a higher value, else a lower one. Then sort by the `CASE`.

It should look something like:

```
SELECT CASE x.total_customers
         WHEN 1 THEN
           'Others'
         ELSE
           x.country
       END country,
       sum(total_customers) total_customers
       FROM (SELECT c.country,
                    count(DISTINCT c.customer_id) total_customers
                    FROM customer c
                    GROUP BY c.country) x
       GROUP BY CASE x.total_customers
                  WHEN 1 THEN
                    'Others'
                  ELSE
                    x.country
                END
       ORDER BY CASE
                  WHEN CASE x.total_customers
                         WHEN 1 THEN
                           'Others'
                         ELSE
                           x.country
                        END = 'Others' THEN
                    1
                  ELSE
                    -1
                END,
                CASE x.total_customers
                  WHEN 1 THEN
                    'Others'
                  ELSE
                    x.country
                END;
```

(Untested, as no DDL or sample data was provided.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select case when customers not in ('India',
'Portugal') then 'Others' else country end as country,
       sum(customers) as customers
from t
group by case when customers not in ('India',
'Portugal') then 'Others' else country end
```